# webpack-angular : bundle includes entire node_modules of library

Tags: angular, webpack, bundle

I have a local ng library in folder `C:/libraries/someLib`
I have an app under `C:/app`

1. In the app, i've installed someLib using `file:` under dependencies.
2. `someLib` has `angular@core` as peerDependency
3. App has `angular@core` as dependency.

Yet the bundle includes the entire `node_modules` from under `libraries`.
What am I missing?

The entire left side of the picture should not exist:
[image]

```
{
  "name": "someLib",
  "version": "0.0.1",
   "peerDependencies": {
     "@angular/common": "^8.1.2",
     "@angular/core": "^8.1.2"
  }
```

--

```
"dependencies": {
    "someLib": "file:../../libraries/dist/someLib",
    "@angular/core": "^8.1.2"
}
```

Comment: It's a problem in dev since i have two instances of different classes, such as `FormControl` and hence code like `x instanceof FormControl` doesn't work, since one control is from the library and one control is from angular@forms. 
I guess in prod build it will be tree shaken, but for can I do for local builds?

Comment: Can you post your tsconfig and webpack config?

Comment: It was an issue with tsconfig. I resolved it by using `paths`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens with local packages, is that the typescript compiler follows the links created by npm and searches for the imports of the library relative to path of the library.

1. Typescript compiler reads the file `../library/src/some.ts` that contains `import @angular/core`.
2. It searches for `@angular` relative to the `library` itself, hence `../library/node_modules/@angular` is being used as the import path.

The solution is to provide in the App project `paths` in `tsconfig.json` which tell the compiler that specific imports should be resolved in specific folders, regardless of where the file is located.

```
{
"compilerOptions": {      
    // Note: these paths are relative to `baseUrl` path.
    "paths": {
        "@angular/*": ["../node_modules/@angular/*"],
        "rxjs": ["../node_modules/rxjs"]
    }
},
```

In this case, any library from any path will always request `@angular` from the `node_modules` of the app and only one copy of `@angular` will be bundled in the `vendor.js`.

This is also specified in the documentation of angular, but initially I didn't get what they want. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-linked-library#use-typesscript-path-mapping-for-peer-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

As a first step it needs to be checked how you are packaging your library. 
I have a sample github repository where i have used ngx-own-carousel in angular lib and used in application.(https://github.com/sanketmaru/ng-lib-sank)

Also you can use this https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-angular-library-series-publishing-ce24bb673275 tutorial for verifying the steps.

Your library code should not ship the 3rd party libraries and every application that uses library must install that separately.

If this doesn't help you can post your code in a sample repo and i can check it out.